# Greedy global RegExp matching in JS

Tags: javascript

I've got this [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec):

```
RegExp('f(o+)', 'g').exec('fofoofooofoooo')
```

In the results array `res`, I was expecting to get:

```
res[1] === 'o'
res[2] === 'oo'
res[3] === 'ooo'
res[4] === 'oooo'
```

but instead I got:

```
res === [ 'fo',
  'o',
  index: 0,
  input: 'fofoofooofoooo' ]
```

Is there a way to get my expected results? I'm getting just the first match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [`.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) instead of `.exec` :

```
'fofoofooofoooo'.match(RegExp('f(o+)', 'g')) // ["fo", "foo", "fooo", "foooo"]
```

> Used to retrieve the matches when matching a string against a regular expression.

Comment: Note, this is because `.exec` does not 'honor' the `g` flag like you'd expect. If you leave off the `g` flag from `match` you'll get the same result as exec gives.